# Cassandra table data modeling

Tags: sql, database, cassandra, nosql

I just started to learn about Cassandra and I have a pretty specific question.
After looking at some videos and tutorials in my understanding there is 1 primary that includes partition keys and clustering keys.

So my question is:
If I have some data that looks like this:

```
Unit: (unit_id, unit_name, unit_description)
```

and I want to save units working hours that look like:

```
Working hours: (unit_id, day, start_time, end_time)
```

What would you suggest the data modeling should look like?
In addition to that, if I have to get all units that work on Sunday or all units that start at 10:00, what would you suggest to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually doing it backwards by starting with how you want to store the data. It's a common mistake for those coming from a traditional relational background.

In Cassandra data modelling, we always start with the application query. For each app query, we would design a CQL table for it.

If your app query is "get units where day is X", we would design a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE units_by_day (
    day text,
    unit_id text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (day, unit_id)
)
```

For each day, there are one or more rows of units (clustered by `unit_id`). To retrieve the units that worked on Sunday:

```
SELECT unit_id FROM units_by_day WHERE day = 'Sunday'
```

If your app query is "get units that worked on day X and started at Y":

```
CREATE TABLE units_by_day_starttime (
    day text,
    start_time time,
    unit_id text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (day, start_time, unit_id)
)
```

And the CQL query would look like:

```
SELECT unit_id FROM units_by_day_starttime
  WHERE day = ?
  AND start_time = ?
```

Note that you can also do range queries on `start_time` like:

```
SELECT unit_id FROM units_by_day_starttime
  WHERE day = ?
  AND start_time >= ?
  AND start_time < ?
```

Cheers!

Comment: Awesome answer, very informative. So by doing it "backwards" I should start with the query and not the actual data model. One more thing, As your answer suggests I would hold a lot of tables for better performance and filtering right? Is that the best practice?

Comment: Yes, we do denormalised tables + data duplication across tables in C* because they are optimised for super fast reads. Writes in C* are cheap so writing to multiple tables is not an issue. We pay a penalty for multiple writes since it means we end up with really fast, optmised reads. Cheers!